# Fetch rows using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

its a simple code. I want to keep a record in the database each time when a file is being  uploaded. And when each time any file is being uploaded I want the user to see he/her's  all uploaded files in a serial from the database. The record keeping while uploading file works fine. But the problem appears while fetching the table containing  all the uploaded file information.

```
//connetion code 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sss");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//file upload code
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"C:/xampp/htdocs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO uploads ( filename, uploaded_on) VALUES ( '{$_FILES['file']['name']}', NOW());");
echo "Stored in: " . "C:/xampp/htdocs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

//fetch rows 
$result =mysqli_query($con, "select * from uploads");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    printf ("%s\n", $row);
}

mysqli_close($con);
}
```

I can feel that there are some serious problem in coding. This is my first time working in mysqli, before I used to code using mysql. need help to know the actual problem and the solution.

**Edited:** 
it returns this,

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\upload_file.php on line 68
Array

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\upload_file.php on line 68
Array

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\upload_file.php on line 68
Array
```

but unfortunately this code is a part of a huge code. so here line 68 is the line where the `$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from uploads");` starts.

Comment: $row is going to be an array. printing an array in string context will just give you `Array`. Your upload handling is also HIGHLY insecure and will allow a malicious user to scribble their files ANYWHERE on your server, on top of being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You could not have written LESS secure code if you'd tried. As well, you're closing your DB connection inside your while loop, so even if everything else was working, you'd only be able to print out **ONE** record anyways.

Comment: I think I discribed what I want and what doesn't work. please my request , read it again. @JohnConde

Comment: @user3017315 - no, you said that your code "doesn't work". Do you get a blank screen? An error message? Does it return no rows? Some rows? All the rows? Print out the wrong thing? The right thing, the wrong way? There are any number of things that might not be working.

Comment: no. see carefully the db connection is not closed inside the while loop. please see it carefully. @MarcB

Comment: ah, I see. You need to properly indent code... And no, you haven't properly described the problem. You just say "this code doesn't work". Doesn't work **HOW**? Crashes? wrong results? deletes something it shouldn't? Kicks your dog?

Comment: @user3017315 - thank you for the error message - @MarcB had it right, and you're trying to print out `$row` as a string - it's an array.

Comment: how can I make it more secure?? how can I prevent it from sql injection?? @MarcB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result =mysqli_query($con, "select * from uploads");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      printf ("%s\n", $row['column_name_1']);
      printf ("%s\n", $row['column_name_2']);
      printf ("%s\n", $row['column_name_3']);
   }
mysqli_close($con);
```

But you should seriously consider looking at the security of your code.

Comment: I don't think that will fix it - that will print the first item from $row on the first iteration; the second item from $row on the second iteration, and so on.

Comment: It will at least fix the error his getting and print out the values of the array.

Comment: It will print out one value from each row of the resultset; from a different column each time. It will also fail if there are more results than there are columns.

Comment: Sorry missed the select * from uploads. Try using mysqli_fetch_assoc(). It returns an associative array.