# PHP, AJAX, HTML, MySQL, get info from database on click of a button

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a **website** that will present a person and his score but behind a **password** protected wall I can increase or decrease the score. I can get the **button to respond** to **ajax** but I cant get it to pass off to the **php** and have the **php** respond with the **sql** entry.

**Ajax**

```
<script>   
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "a1.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.success) {
                $("#responsecontainer").html(msg);
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

In all honesty I have spent so much time on this flipping ajax problem I dont even think I can understand what I was trying to do at this point...Sorry lads.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test_db_usr";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "test_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT id, name, points FROM points";
//how do I send this back to my html file?


$conn->close();
?>
```

So my goal is when I click the "next button" the system will move onto the next ID number in the MySQL database. I have the database set up and I can pull info through PHP but I cant get a button click to do anything!

I also plan to have two buttons one that adds a point and one that removes one and they would pass this info off to the database...but one step at a time for me.

Sorry if this isnt enough info Ill do my best to fill in any gaps I left out.

Regards.

Comment: Do you get error?can you post the error?

Comment: you need something like `$result = $conn->query($sql); while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "<div>". $row["id"]. " ". $row["name"]. " ". $row["points"]."<div>"); }` see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, I suggest you see the answer to the question that I am linking to below.

[Fetch rows using mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125791/fetch-rows-using-mysqli)

More importantly, you need to read the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Answer (score 0):

U have to mention hidden field score "id" and action field which will be "add" or "remove" which be set upon button click and score field,in click event set action field like $("#action").val("remove"); and add data:$("#form").serialize(); option in your Ajax call, receive posted fields in the server side and execute SQL I.e. Update ..., echo them and update response.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, points FROM points";
//how do I send this back to my html file?
```

i think you need to add another `AJAX GET` call  thats something like this

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "a1.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

and in your php code you need to return a JSON response thats something like

```
return json_encode(array('success', data));
```

and use this response to append updated data on your html to get updated values