# MySQL will not SELECT * FROM database

Tags: php, mysql

When I select all from my database, it only returns one row. I have changed it to `select "column name" from database where "blank" = 1` and set multiple rows to have "blank" = 1 and it still only returns one row.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("host", "database", "password", "database");
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("There was an error, Please try again");
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `news`";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
    $imageTest = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

When I test this and print out the array with

```
<?php print_r($imageTest); ?>
```

It only comes back with one row (there are currently 3 test rows in the database)

I know Im probably missing something super small. Ive never really worked a project that I needed to select more than one row of items in a column.

I have another database being used in the same project that Im not having any issues with in its intended function but when I went to that one and tested the same thing, it returned the same results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch rows using mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125791/fetch-rows-using-mysqli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), `mysqli_fetch_array` fetch a single row from the result set every time it's called. Go for the following code to retrieve all of them:

```
$rows = array();
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    $rows[] = $row;

print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score -1):

[`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) fetches a single row from the result set.

What you're looking for is [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) (or a `while` loop with `mysqli_fetch_array` ).

**I would advise against using `mysqli_*` functions, and suggest using `PDO`.**
Please refer to the following resources as to why I hold this opinion:

[mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison

Comment: Why do you advise against `mysqli_*`?

Comment: @maxisme Because of named parameters, driver independance and a few other gotchas. I've edited my answer with resources.